# ElasticSearch search result in some arbitrary order

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I'm trying to get the elastic search result in des order to populate the grid .

**Sample**

```
 var search = new SearchRequest<Dummyclass>
            {
                Query = matchAllQuery,
                From = input.SkipCount,
                Size = input.MaxResultCount,
                
                Sort = new List<ISort>
                {
                     new FieldSort { Field = "_score" ,Order=SortOrder.Descending  }
                },
                TrackScores = true
            };
```

But this result  in some arbitrary order. Any inputs / pointers ?

Example : Dummy class contains FullName Fee SubmittedDate props

**Expected**

XXXXX, 3421, Feb20th2021

YYYYYY,2341, Jan15th2021

ZZZZ, 1234,  Dec24th2020

**Current**:

ZZZZ, 1234,  Dec24th2020

YYYYYY,2341, Jan15th2021

XXXXX, 3421, Feb20th2021

Comment: The results are sorted by `_score` descending by default. Are you able to edit your question to provide more detail about the results you're seeing?

Comment: @RussCam provided the sample result